# Xamarin Studio 6.0 F# Array.tail produces compilation error

Tags: arrays, xamarin, compiler-errors, f#

i have been using VS2015 on Win8.1 to develop in F# but i bought an iMAC recently and installed Xamarin Studio 6.0 for MacOS X elCapitan 10.11.3

there's some code that compiles normally on VS2015 and i'm trying to compile it on the iMAC.

Array.tail does work in F# interactive but
i have a compilation error for Array.tail

Projects/MyAlgos/MyAlgos/Program.fs(25,25): Error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'tail' is not defined (FS0039) (MyAlgos)

in the Solution explorer panel in Xamarin, i have setup Target Framework as .NET Framework 4.5.2, (like it is setup in VS2015)

```
//////// Travelling Salesman problem ////////


open System
open System.Collections
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.IO

open System.Windows

open FSharp.Charting

//open MyLibrary
//open MyLibrary.MyUsefulFunctions
//open MyLibrary.MyCollections

exception InnerError of string


let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

///////////////// preparing the data /////////////////

// format of the files
//[number_of_cities]
//[x_1] [y_1] // coordinate

let x = File.ReadAllLines "C:\Users\Fagui\Documents\GitHub\Learning Fsharp\Algos\Algos\Stanford Algo II\Algo II - PA5 - TSP.txt"

let split (text:string)=
    text.Split [|'\t';' '|]

let splitInto2Values (A: string []) =  
    (float A.[0],float A.[1])

let parseLine (line:string) = 
    line
    |> split 
    |> splitInto2Values



let num_cities = int x.[0]

let cities = x |> Array.tail |> Array.map parseLine //  [x_1][y_1]
```

i also have this related warning

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.4.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Warning: TargetFrameworkVersion 'v4.5.2' not supported by this toolset (ToolsVersion: 4.0). (MyAlgos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> let cities = x |> Array.tail |> Array.map parseLine
>
> Error FS0039: The value, constructor, namespace or type 'tail' is not defined (FS0039) (MyAlgos)

I am not having any issues with `Array.tail` not being found in compiled code (or interactive).

Have you tried creating a F# Console project and doing just a simple `Array.tail` test? See the sample source below.

#### Source:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let array3 = [| 1; 2; 3 |]
    let array2 = array3 |> Array.tail
    let array1 = array2 |> Array.tail
    printfn "%A\n%A\n%A" array3 array2 array1

    0 // return an integer exit code
```

#### Output:

```
[|1; 2; 3|]
[|2; 3|]
[|3|]

Press any key to continue...
```

#### My Version info:

```
>fsharpc
F# Compiler for F# 4.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License
>mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3
```

#### Remove Framework Warning:

To remove the framework warning you can set your project to "Mono / Net 4.5"

[image]

Comment: Great to hear... happy F#'ing;-)